# How to get exact coordinate of each word of pdf using itextsharp?

Tags: c#, itext

I have implemented LocationTextExtractionStrategy of my own. The renderinfo in some pdfs reads combination of words as chunks while in others it reads character by character

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;

namespace PDFAnnotater
{
    public class TestLTES : LocationTextExtractionStrategy
    {
        int WordIndex;
        //Hold each coordinate
        public List<RectAndText> myPoints = new List<RectAndText>();
        public string formedText="";
        public Vector[] charBottomLeft;
        public Vector[] charTopRight;
        public int Counter=0;
        //The string that we're searching for
        public string TextToSearchFor { get; set; }
        public bool found = false;

    //How to compare strings
    public System.Globalization.CompareOptions CompareOptions { get; set; }

    public TestLTES(string textToSearchFor, System.Globalization.CompareOptions compareOptions = System.Globalization.CompareOptions.None)
    {
        TextToSearchFor = textToSearchFor;
        CompareOptions = compareOptions;
        charBottomLeft = new Vector[1];
        charTopRight = new Vector[1];

    }
    public TestLTES(int index, string textToSearchFor, System.Globalization.CompareOptions compareOptions = System.Globalization.CompareOptions.None)
    {
        TextToSearchFor = textToSearchFor;
        CompareOptions = compareOptions;
        WordIndex = index;

    }


    //Automatically called for each chunk of text in the PDF
    public override void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        base.RenderText(renderInfo);
        //See if the current chunk contains the text
        if (renderInfo.GetText().Length >= this.TextToSearchFor.Length)
        {
            if (renderInfo.GetText().Split().Contains(this.TextToSearchFor))
            {
                var startPosition = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(renderInfo.GetText(), this.TextToSearchFor, this.CompareOptions);


                //Grab the individual characters
                var chars = renderInfo.GetCharacterRenderInfos().Skip(startPosition).Take(this.TextToSearchFor.Length).ToList();
                var textpos = renderInfo.GetText();
                //.GetCharacterRenderInfos().Skip(startPosition).Take(this.TextToSearchFor.Length).ToList();


                //Grab the first and last character
                var firstChar = chars.First();
                var lastChar = chars.Last();


                //Get the bounding box for the chunk of text
                var bottomLeft = firstChar.GetDescentLine().GetStartPoint();
                var topRight = lastChar.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();

                //Create a rectangle from it
                var rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(
                                                        bottomLeft[Vector.I1],
                                                        bottomLeft[Vector.I2],
                                                        topRight[Vector.I1],
                                                        topRight[Vector.I2]
                                                        );

                IntegerRectangle TempRect = new IntegerRectangle();
                TempRect.Top = (int)Math.Truncate(rect.Top);
                TempRect.Bottom = (int)Math.Truncate(rect.Bottom);
                TempRect.Left = (int)Math.Truncate(rect.Left);
                TempRect.Right = (int)Math.Truncate(rect.Right);


                //Add this to our main collection
                this.myPoints.Add(new RectAndText(TempRect, rect, this.TextToSearchFor, WordIndex));
            }

            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (renderInfo.GetText() != "" && renderInfo.GetText()!=" ")
            {
                string[] renderTextArray = renderInfo.GetText().Split();
                for (int i = 0; i < renderTextArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (TextToSearchFor.Contains(renderTextArray[i]))
                    {
                        if (charBottomLeft != null && charTopRight != null)
                        {
                            var startPosition = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(renderTextArray[i], this.TextToSearchFor, this.CompareOptions);
                            var chars = renderInfo.GetCharacterRenderInfos().Skip(startPosition).Take(this.TextToSearchFor.Length).ToList();
                            //Grab the first and last character
                            var firstChar = chars.First();
                            var lastChar = chars.Last();


                            //Get the bounding box for the chunk of text
                            var bottomLeft = firstChar.GetDescentLine().GetStartPoint();
                            var topRight = lastChar.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();
                            if (FoundChars.foundCharsList.Contains(renderTextArray[i] + bottomLeft + topRight))
                                return;

                            formedText = formedText + renderTextArray[i];
                            if (Counter > 0)
                            {
                                charBottomLeft = ReAllocate(charBottomLeft, Counter + 1);
                                charTopRight = ReAllocate(charTopRight, Counter + 1);
                            }
                            charBottomLeft[Counter] = bottomLeft;
                            charTopRight[Counter] = topRight;
                            Counter++;
                            FoundChars.foundCharsList.Add(renderTextArray[i] + bottomLeft + topRight);
                            if (formedText == TextToSearchFor)
                            {
                                var bLeft = charBottomLeft[0];
                                var tRight = charTopRight[Counter - 1];
                                Counter = 0;
                                formedText = "";
                                charBottomLeft = null;
                                charTopRight = null;
                                var rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(
                                                               bLeft[Vector.I1],
                                                               bLeft[Vector.I2],
                                                               tRight[Vector.I1],
                                                               tRight[Vector.I2]
                                                               );

                                IntegerRectangle TempRect = new IntegerRectangle();
                                TempRect.Top = (int)Math.Truncate(rect.Top);
                                TempRect.Bottom = (int)Math.Truncate(rect.Bottom);
                                TempRect.Left = (int)Math.Truncate(rect.Left);
                                TempRect.Right = (int)Math.Truncate(rect.Right);


                                //Add this to our main collection
                                this.myPoints.Add(new RectAndText(TempRect, rect, this.TextToSearchFor, WordIndex));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private Vector[] ReAllocate(Vector[] arr,int counter)
    {

            Vector[] ReAllocatedArray = new Vector[counter];

                for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j++)
                {
                  ReAllocatedArray[j] = arr[j];
                }

            return ReAllocatedArray;

      }
   }
}
```

In some cases it is working properly while in some cases it is not.
Is there some other feasible way to get the coordinate of a particular word.

Comment: In which cases is it not working properly? The `getDescentLine()` and `getAscentLine()` functions return boundaries as reported by the font. Is it possible the font is reporting lines that are either too high or low?

Comment: *"In some cases it is working properly while in some cases it is not"* - what do you mean by not working properly?

Comment: By not working properly means my program is not giving desired results when it reads text chunks as characters or a group of characters. For example it reads hello as h, el, lo. Here my logic is not working properly.

Comment: the chunks can be anything from single glyphs to a complete line. They correspond to the chunks drawn atomically by the pdf generating software. You need to collect events until you are sure you have all chunks from the same line.

Comment: I have grouped all the chunks according to their y-coordinate problem is getting exact x-coordinate of chunks. Suppose if it reads 'Hello World' as three chunks i.e hell, owo, rld. How will i get exact x-coordinate of 'Hello World'

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve this is to look at how SimpleTextExtractionStrategy works.
In this strategy, iText also processes chunks and turns them into a String.

The general workflow is:

- get all TextRenderInfo events
- turn them into CharacterRenderInfo events
- sort the list of CharacterRenderInfo events in logical reading order
- go over the list, aggregating characters into words if they are close together (this is a heuristic, iText uses 'less than the width of a single space in the given font').
- now you have the boundaries (provided by CharacterRenderInfo.getBoundingBox) and the words

Comment: *"sort the list of CharacterRenderInfo events in logical reading order"* - sorting only is done by the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`, not by the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` you mention.

Comment: I also mention "general workflow". To clarify, the inspiration for solving this problem should be based on SimpleTextExtractionStrategy and the workflow in this answer.